# Starting julia with a lot of workers leads to them just timing out

Tags: julia

I am on a grid with roughly 1000 cores. Now when I start a script like this

`julia -p 500 myScript.jl`

It just results in most of the workers timing out saying "Could not connect to master within 60 seconds." What am I supposed to do about that?

At `-p 100` this whole mess starts with maybe one process timing out.

Comment: what if you add them incrementally via `addprocs(N)`?

Comment: That seems to be the obvious workaround and I am implementing that right now. But it seems kinda stupid that I have to do that. Whatever I am implementing right now is so agnostic to my problem, that the devs could have put that code in by themself.

Comment: File an issue in JuliaLang.